# Who are the parents of Devi Lakshmi?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, goddess

As we know that Devi Sati is reborn as Devi Parvati, the daughter of Himavat and Mainavati, and is named Parvati. Which shows King Himavat and Mainavati are parents of Devi Parvati.

But there is no information about parents of Devi Lakshmi. The only thing we know about her is she springs with other precious things from the foam of the ocean of milk when it is churned by the gods and demons for the recovery of Amṛta. I have read it somewhere That she is daughter of Patal.(Can't cite source right now)

We know birth, childhood and life story of Devi Parvati. Similarly, do we have any information about Devi Lakshmi?

Who are the parents of Devi Lakshmi?

In other words  I want to have all information about In law's of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: Lakshmi - Narayana are eternal consorts. They can't be separated in reality. But as a part of their leela, Devi Lakshmi took birth, as in Samudra Madhana episode.

Comment: Lakshmi is born out of ocean of milk so she is called MakaraalayaKanyakaa, SaagarSambhavaa.

Answer (score 3):

The more popular account of Lakshmi Devi's manifestation is the episode of the churning of the ocean. It is mentioned in the MahAbhArata as well as in the PurAnas.

According to MahAbhArata, Lakshmi Devi Or Sri appeared from clarified butter (or Ghee) during Samudra Manthana as sitting on a white lotus:

> SrirantarmutpannA ghritAt pAnduravAsini ( Adi Parva 18-35 )

PurAnas like the BhAgavata (8.8.14) and the Padma (Srishti Khanda 4-58-59) also repeats the same event.

But Lakshmi Devi's parents are also mentioned in not one but many PurAnas as **Maharshi Bhrigu (father) and KhyAti (mother).**

> **Bhriguh KhyAtAm** MahAbhAgah PatnyAm PutrAnajijanat |
>  dhAtArancha
>   vidhAtAram sriyancha bhagavatparAm ||
>
> .......
>
> From MahabhAg Bhrigu's wife KhyAti's womb were born three children
>   named DhAta, VidhAtA and Bhagavataparayana Sri (or Lakshmi).
>
> **BhAgavata purANa 4.2.42**

The VishNu purANa says the same:

> Devau DhAtA VidhatArau **Bhrigoh KhyAti Rasuyataah** |
>  Shriyancha
>   Devadevasya Patni NArAyanasya YA ||
>
> .............
>
> Bhrigu's wife KhyAti gave birth to two Devas called DhAtA and VidhAtA
>   and Sri who is the consort of NArAyana.
>
> **VishNu PurANa's first part, 8.13**

The BrahmAnda purANa also repeats the same:

> Bhrigoh khyAtirvijajnehatha iswarau sukhadukkhayoh |
>   SubhAsubhapradAtarau sarva prAna VrtAviha ||
>  Devau dhAtA vidhAtArau
>   manvantara vichArinau | 
> TayorjyeshthA tu bhagini devi srir loka
>   bhAvini || 
> sA tu nArAyanam devam pati mAsAdya shobhanam | 
>   NArAyanatmajau sAddvi valotsAhou vyajAyat ||
>
> ...........
>
> Bhrigu and his wife KhyAti gave birth to two sons named DhAtA and VidhAtA and a daughter named Shri or Lakshmi. Lakshmi obtained as her husband NArAyana and thereafter gave birth to two sons called Bala (strength) and UtsAha (enthusiasm).
>
> **BrahmAnda purANa 29. 1-3.**

And, that is why MahAlakshmi is also known as **BhArgavi.**

Comment: What is the connection of Daughter of Maharshi Bhrigu and KhyAti  and churning ocean.

Comment: As Devi Parvati did tapasya to be wife of Lord Shiva. How did she become wife of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: No relation. That is another account of how Lakshmi manifested given in other Scriptures. But as far as biological parents are concerned then only Bhrigu and Khyati can be mentioned. @PraveenGaikwad

Comment: did she did any tapsya to be wife of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: I don't know those details but as per Mahabharata she is mentioned as daughter of Daksha and there her husband is Dharma. If you want i can add it. @PraveenGaikwad

Comment: means she has 2 husbands. one dharma and another Lord Vishnu

Comment: There her husband is mentioned as Dharma. Obviously Lakshmi is well known as Vishnu's wife. I just said what i found. @PraveenGaikwad

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad There is only one husband. That is Lord Vishnu. Dharma's wife is not Lakshmi.

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting correct answer which is accompanied with not one but multiple sources??

Comment: As per my knowledge, Rishi Bhrigu put curse on all lokas (coz of Indra) that all will get shree heen and Lakshami will be vanished from all lokas. Thus every gold and other luxuries vanished since Lakshmi was no longer available. She came from Samundra manthan after. She has to appear from Samundra manthan coz she had no other choice coz of Rishi Bhrigu's curse. This incident has mentioned in Shiva Purana.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad Devi Lakshmi had left her abode when rishi Durvasa cursed Indra that he would lose all the riches. Later when the Samudra Manthan was done, goddess Lakshmi re-emerged along with other riches.