# When Goddess Parvati was the daughter of sage Bhrigu?

Tags: name, parvati, bhrigu

Meaning of Bhargavi is female descendant of sage Bhrigu. When checking meaning of names, I figured out that Bhargavi is name of Parvati too because

> Goddess Parvati was the daughter of Bhrigu, hence she got the name Bhargavi ~ [babycenter](https://www.babycenter.in/babyname/1080179/bhargavi)

I am aware of Goddess Lakshmi's incarnation as sage Bhrigu's daughter but what's the story of Goddess Parvati's incarnation as sage Bhrigu's daughter?

---

**Update**

[This website](https://m.pitarau.com/meaning-of-bhargavi) says

> In ancient India, Sage Bhrigu was Shiva's devotee. He had married kardama's daughter Khyati. In answer to the prayer of that couple, Goddess Parvathi was born as their daughter. Because she was the daughter of Bhrigu, she got the name 'Bhargavi'. She later married the Hindu God Shiva's avatar 'ChandraShekar' meaning one who holds the moon and brings solutions to all problems.

Answer (score 6):

Goddess Parvati was never the daughter of Bhrigu. She is Adi Parashakti incarnated as Lord Shiva's wife and from her emerged the 10 Mahavidyas of which the last one is Kamala or Lakshmi. And Lakshmi is Bhargavi and that's how Parvati's one name is also that.

The story of how the Dasha Mahavidyas emerged from Adi Parashakti/Sati/Parvati is given in Devi Purana and is detailed already in the answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20742/4732).

Quoting from that answer:

> Once the greatest of Yogis, Lord Maheswara worshiped MahAdevi and
>   obtained from her the boon that She will be his wife. Lord Brahma upon
>   realizing that soon MahAdevi will manifest herself as per the boon,
>   orders one of his favorite sons, Daksha, to engage in penance so that
>   the would be consort of Lord Shiva can be his daughter.
>
> Daksha thus did a severe tapasyA to MahAdevi and she appeared before
>   him. When asked what boon does he want, Daksha said he wants MahAdevi
>   to be born as his daughter. MahAdevi granted that boon and said when
>   she will descend to be the wife of Lord Shiva she will take birth from
>   Daksha's wife Prasuti's womb. But she also reminded him that once
>   Daksha's merits end or if he somehow disreagrds her, she will leave
>   him instantly.

The Daksha Yajna episode is well-known so I am not repeating it in full here. When, Lord Shiva saw that Sati was adamant to attend his father's Yajna inspite of his disapproval got a little angry and reprimanded her saying:

> Janami vagvahirbhutAm tvAmaham dakshakanyake |
>  yatharuchi kuru
>   tvancha mamajyAm ki pratikshase ||
>
> I know that you are not bound by my orders, so do as you please, why
>   are you waiting for my consent?
>
> Upon hearing Shiva's strong words Devi got angry. And thought to
>   hersef that Shiva, upon obtaining her as his wife, forgot her real
>   form (which is of Parama Shakti). So let me abandon him and my proud
>   father and stay in my own swarupa and in my own lila for sometime.
>
> tyaktanamapi darpishtham pitarncha prajApatim |
>  SamsthAsyAmi
>   kiyatkAlam swasthAnam nijalilAyA ||
>
> On thinking thus, Devi assumed the terrible form of MahAkAli. Which
>   was of a Goddess who is dark complexioned, digamabari (without
>   clothes), lolajihvA (tongue hanging out and clasped with the teeth),
>   with disheveled hair and wearing garland comprised of slain heads.
>
> Lord Shiva was terrified on seeing Goddess's such terrible form and
>   tried to escape from that place immediately.
>
> Upon seeing her terrified consort Shiva, Devi, out of mercy and in
>   order to block all the ten directions (so that Shiva can not escape
>   through any one of them), assumed ten different forms with each
>   blocking one direction.
>
> Evam patim vikshya bhayAbhibhutakam dayAnvitA tat prati vAranecchayA |
>   sarvAsu dikshu kshanamAtramadhyataha stithA cha bhutvA
>   dashamurtayastadA |
>
> Whichever directions Lord Shiva tries to escape through, finds one or
>   the other terrible forms of Devi guarding there. So, unable to find an
>   way to escape Lord Shiva closed his eyes out of fear and upon opening
>   them again found the terrible Goddess MahAkAli right in front of him.
>
> Lord Shiva asked " Who are you ShyAmA (the dark complexioned one)?
>   Where is my beloved Sati?"
>
> Devi laughingly replied " Can't you recognize me? Iam your own Sati.
>   Im the SrishtistithisamhArakArini SukshmA Parkriti. For being your
>   wife I have become fair complexioned (Gauri). The ten Devis that you
>   see around you are also my forms. Hence, O MahAmati Shambhu, do not
>   fear:
>
> Sati said to her husband who was afflicted with fear " The Goddess who
>   is in your front is BhimanayanA MahakAli, in the sky (or in the
>   antariksha direction) is TArA, on the right side is ChinnamastA, on
>   your left is Bhuvaneswari, behind you is BagalAmukhi, at the
>   south-east corner (Agni Kona) is DhumAvati, **in the south-west corner
>   (Nairitkona) there is KamalA**, in the north-west corner (VAyukona)
>   there is MAtangi , in the north-east corner (IshAna kona) there is
>   Shodashi (Tripura Sundari) and in your own self I am existing as
>   Bhairavi.
>
> Now, if you want I can teach that proud Daksha a lesson by destroying
>   his Yajna.

A somewhat different account of the appearance of the Mahavidyas (from Goddess Parvati) is also found in the Devi Bhagavtam which is also given in my linked answer.

So, whatever the story is, the fact is all the Mahavidyas, including the 10th or Kamala, emerged from Goddess Parvati only.

And Kamala is identified as Goddess Lakshmi who again is known as Bhargavi, the daughter of Bhrigu (as shown in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20627/4732)). So that's how Goddess Parvati's one name is also Bhargavi.

Comment: Pls see updated Q...I think this transitive relationship A->B->C->D = B->D is not the case..

Comment: You can disagree but according to me that is only the case. @YDS If someone can prove me wrong with authentic sources I wdn't hv any problem in changing my mind.